# LEFT Join and data in right table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a problem with my sql join request, I need to get lines of left table who are not referenced in right table or referenced in right table with status equal to 0 for my user 1. 
I also need the field status of right table
Here is my two tables :

```
Table left
ID | title
1  | Title 1
2  | Title 2
3  | Title 3
4  | Title 4
5  | Title 5

Table right
ID | status | user | left_id
1  |    0   |   1  |    1
2  |    0   |   50 |    1
3  |    1   |   1  |    2
4  |    0   |   50 |    2
5  |    0   |   1  |    3
6  |    1   |   50 |    3
```

My goal is to get this result :

```
left.ID | left.title | right.status | right.user
   1    |  Title 1   |      0       |      1 
   3    |  Title 3   |      0       |      1 
   4    |  Title 4   |     NULL     |    NULL
   5    |  Title 5   |     NULL     |    NULL
```

I need right informations to do some verifications on status field if exist or not.

Here is my request for the moment :

```
SELECT l.title, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id AND r.user = 1 AND r.status = 0
```

The problem is I got the line Title 2, I don't kwon how to remove this line.
If someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You will always get title 2 as you are selecting from that table and doing left join, so server can't cut it off ... best you can do here is to add `where` condition and exclude what you don't need, that's only thing you can do if you want to stick with `left join`

Comment: There is no difference between title 2 and title 4. Why don't you like to get title 2?

Comment: I used left join but if there is another solution I will check it and accept it. To @Holger title 2 is in status 1 for my user, and title 4 haven't any informations in right table.

Comment: Have you tried Right join?

Comment: @LJ01 No i don't tried, because I need all informations of left table, I don't put all the informations here because there is 5 more fields. And with a right join it's will be complicate to get left table informations no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, r.user, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id 
WHERE r.left_id IS NULL or (r.user = 1 AND r.status = 0)
```

The `r.left_id IS NULL` will keep the left records that are not in right table and `or (r.user = 1 AND r.status = 0)` will keep left records with requested values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use LEFT JOIN, you can't use the join condition to filter on status. Filter in the WHERE clause instead.

```
SELECT l.title, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id
WHERE r.ID IS NULL OR (r.status = 0 and r.user = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. First join with ids and then filter for your condition in where close

```
SELECT l.title, r.status
FROM left as l
LEFT JOIN right as r ON l.id = r.left_id 
Where r.user = 1 AND r.status = 0
```

Comment: Your solution don't display left table datas not linked in right table. I need them too. But thanks